# I have a form with 4 radio buttons that change a part of the form. What is the best way to handle it?

Tags: forms, input-fields, progressive-disclosure

Is a site for a boosting service for a videogame. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jPMA.png
(Please ignore the spelling)

Depending what option is selected (type of boost) the form will change a little. All the section on the right (Desired Rank, the img, and both drop menus) will change to a big number and a range slider.

So i have two questions:

1. When the user go into the form should, the expected to be, most used option preloaded? or be all hidden but the radio buttons, and display the rest when the user pick a option?
2. When the user click on a option, then click in another, should it change all the form, just the part that will change or maybe both columns (Current Rank and Desired Rank)

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 - it depends: A) are you more interested in ensuring the user picks the most appropriate option without any type of influention? Hide all dependent fields. B) by the form usage you clearly understand that the majority of users will pick one popular option, mostly without exploring the remaining options? R: present that popular option selected.

Q2 - the most important point is to ensure users understand the form dependency from the top option. Also preserve any values submitted on the forms, even if users change the top selection to check the other options.

Would recommend conducting user tests to understand if users still have any doubts with the screen interactions and the form options.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something along these lines when [buying an iPad Pro](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-pro/32gb-gold-wifi). The initial colour option changes the image on the left hand side and collapses the selection showing you what you've selected.

#### Step 1:

[image]

#### Step 2 (after clicking on colour):

[image]

#### Step 3 (after selecting Storage):

[image]